# Message Buffer for TCP Listener

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcplistener

I have a TCP Listener in a vb.net class that listens for data that another program sends out. The problem is it sends the data at a faster rate than my processing routine can process it. The routine will be about half way thru processing the last message and here comes another message on the listening port and it starts the processing without finishing the other message.
I want to add a message buffer so all incoming text strings are placed in a stack and when my processing routine gets done it will pull the next string out of the stack and work with it and then pull the next one until the stack is empty
I'm not sure of the best way to do this. I'm looking to see what someone thinks would be the best way to handle this.

TIA
Rick

```
     Private Sub TCPListening()
    Dim CommandString As String = ""
    Dim ParamLength As Short
    Dim ADIFStr As String = ""
    Dim tmpStr As String = ""
    Dim tmpBool As Boolean
    Dim paramStr As String = ""
    Dim xcvrfreq As String = ""
    Dim xcvrmode As String = ""
    Dim prsvsplit As String = ""
    Dim Arr() As String
    Dim decimalstr As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
    Dim thousandsstr As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator

    If ExternalTcpListener Is Nothing Then
        ExternalTcpListener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ExternalTCPIP), ExternalTCPPort)
        ExternalTcpListener.Start()
    End If
    Try
        Dim responseString As String = ""
        Dim sendBytes As [Byte]()
        Dim ExternaltcpClient As TcpClient = ExternalTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient()
     While True
            Debug.Print("Start While")
            Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = ExternaltcpClient.GetStream()
            Dim bytes(ExternaltcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
            networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(ExternaltcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
            Dim Sentdata As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)

            ttimer.start()
            Sentdata = Replace(Sentdata, vbNullChar, "")
            If Sentdata <> "" Then Debug.Print("SendData= " & Sentdata)
            If InStrRev(Sentdata, "<command:") > 8 Then
                '<command:10>CmdSetFreq<parameters:23><xcvrfreq:10> 7,185.000<command:10>CmdGetFreq<parameters:0>
                'If multiple commands are recieved this section of the routine splits them up and processes each one as seperate commands.
                Sentdata = Strings.Replace(Sentdata, "<command", "|<command")
                Arr = Split(Sentdata, "|")
                Debug.Print(" Arr=" & UBound(Arr))
                For x = 1 To UBound(Arr)
                    Sentdata = Arr(x)
                    Debug.Print(" New " & Sentdata)
                    If InStr(Sentdata, "<command") Then
                        tmpStr = Sentdata
                        tmpStr = Right(Sentdata, Len(Sentdata) - 1)
                        CommandString = Extract(tmpStr, ">", "<")
                        ParamLength = Extract(Sentdata, "<parameters:", ">")
                        Select Case CommandString

                            Case "CmdSetFreqMode", "CmdQSXSplit", "CmdSetFreq", "CmdSetTXFreq", "CmdSetMode", "CmdSplit" ', "CmdTX", "CmdRX"
                                Station.ActiveWindow.SetExternalTCPCommandsInvoke(Sentdata)
                                'The above commands are processed and handled in EntryWindow.SetExternalTCPCommands
                            Case "CmdGetFreq"
                                '<command:10>CmdGetFreq<parameters:0>
                                Debug.Print("NI1Inside: " & CommandString & "  " & Sentdata)
                                If ParamLength = 0 Then
                                    tmpStr = Format(Val(Station.ActiveRadio.Frequency), "##,###.000")
                                    responseString = "<CmdFreq:" & Len(tmpStr) & ">" & tmpStr
                                    Debug.Print("[R1] " & responseString)
                                    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseString)
                                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
                                    'LogError("CmdGetFreq1Response - ElapsedTime: " & ttimer.ElapsedMilliseconds)
                                End If
                            Case "CmdGetTXFreq"
                                '<command:12>CmdGetTXFreq<parameters:0>
                                Debug.Print("NIInside: " & CommandString & "  " & Sentdata)
                                If ParamLength = 0 Then
                                    tmpStr = Format(Val(Station.ActiveRadio.TXFreq), "##,###.000")
                                    If Len(tmpStr) = 0 Then
                                        responseString = "<CmdTXFreq:4>.000"
                                    Else
                                        responseString = "<CmdTXFreq:" & Len(tmpStr) & ">" & tmpStr
                                    End If
                                    Debug.Print("[R1] " & responseString)
                                    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseString)
                                    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
                                    'LogError("CmdGetTXFreq1Response - ElapsedTime: " & ttimer.ElapsedMilliseconds)
                                End If
                        end select
                            End If

                Next
                'End If

            ElseIf InStr(Sentdata, "command") And InStrRev(Sentdata, "<command:") < 8 Then
                'This section of the routine processes single commands that are sent via the Listener
                tmpStr = Sentdata
                tmpStr= Right(Sentdata, Len(Sentdata) - 1)
                CommandString = Extract(tmpStr, ">", "<")
                ParamLength = Extract(Sentdata, "parameters:", ">")
                Select Case CommandString

                    Case "CmdSetFreqMode", "CmdQSXSplit", "CmdSetFreq", "CmdSetTXFreq", "CmdSetMode", "CmdSplit" ', "CmdTX", "CmdRX"
                        Station.ActiveWindow.SetExternalTCPCommandsInvoke(Sentdata)
                        'The above commands are processed and handled in EntryWindow.SetExternalTCPCommands

                    Case "CmdGetFreq"
                        '<command:10>CmdGetFreq<parameters:0>
                        Debug.Print("NI2Inside: " & CommandString & "  " & Sentdata)
                        If ParamLength = 0 Then
                            tmpStr = Format(Val(Station.ActiveRadio.Frequency), "##,###.000")
                            responseString = "<CmdFreq:" & Len(tmpStr) & ">" & tmpStr
                            Debug.Print("[R] " & responseString)
                            sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseString)
                            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
                            'LogError("CmdGetFreqResponse - ElapsedTime: " & ttimer.ElapsedMilliseconds)
                        End If
                    Case "CmdGetTXFreq"
                        '<command:12>CmdGetTXFreq<parameters:0> 
                        Debug.Print("NI2Inside: " & CommandString & "  " & Sentdata)
                        If ParamLength = 0 Then
                            tmpStr = Format(Val(Station.ActiveRadio.TXFreq), "##,###.000")
                            If Len(tmpStr) = 0 Then
                                responseString = "<CmdTXFreq:4>.000"
                            Else
                                responseString = "<CmdTXFreq:" & Len(tmpStr) & ">" & tmpStr
                            End If
                            Debug.Print("[R] " & responseString)
                            sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseString)
                            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
                            'LogError("CmdGetTXFreqResponse - ElapsedTime: " & ttimer.ElapsedMilliseconds)
                        End If
```

There is alot of code missing but it gives you the general idea of what is happening.

Comment: When you say that there _"comes another message on the listening port"_, do you mean that the already connected client sends another message, or that a _new client_ connects and sends its message? || Also, what is the exact problem you're experiencing? Why can't another message be received while processing the first one?

Comment: The already connected client sends another message and the listener recieves the message and stops processing the old message and starts processing the new one. The listener is at the top of the routine and after receiving a message 
 the listening routine breaks the message down. After that is goes thru a series of a series of case statements depending on certain commands in the message. If at any point while processing the message and new one comes in  instead of finishing the processing and sending the results back to the other program it starts the from the top of the routine again.

Comment: Okay. Please edit your post to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can help you identify the issue.

Comment: I have added the code. There are some case statements missing but this shows the layout..

Comment: Hi, sorry for getting back to you so late. I've been really busy the entire weekend... It's quite a bit of code you added there. Could you please try to narrow it down to a smaller example? It's not easy for someone who's not involved in the project to try to understand that much code, but from what I can see nothing should cause it to start over. Please check the MCVE link I shared in my previous comment. Restarting from scratch, only adding the very parts necessary to reproduce the problem, is a good way both to debug code _and_ make it easier for others to understand and test.

Comment: Later tonight I will copy my debug's and show you how it runs thru.the routine.if its doing easy work its ok but when I have to doing more intensive work is when it happens..